# install packages on MacOS m1 Monterey

Tags: macos, vue.js, apple-m1

I have a problem with installation packages on my macOS Monterey machine with m1 chip. My project has been created using Vue2/NuxtJS. And when I try to install packages with command sudo npm i - I get errors:

[image]

Please help, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: i just started an install on a new M1, too, and am having the same problems. I'll let you know if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same issue. In my case, I had to downgrade npm version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30685328)